# Trouble with Log progression

Tags: powershell

I'm trying copy logs in numerical order and I want my output.txt to log the last file copied however I'm running to a problem where when my script goes from log_9.txt to Log_10.txt the value that gets put into my text file stays at log_9.txt even though it copies all the files

```
dir c:\PS1 *.bat | ForEach {
    $variable = "$($_.Name) 'n$(Get-content $_.FullName)"
    Set-Content -Value $variable -Path c:\PS1\Output.txt
    $pull = Get-Content C:\PS1\Output.txt
    copy-item $source\$pull -Destination $dest -Verbose

        }
      }
```

Comment: `dir C:\PS1 *.bat` by default produces an _alphabetically_ sorted list of files, in which `log_1.txt` is first, followed by `log_10.txt`, then `log_2.txt` all the way up to `log_9.txt` (if there are ten log files numbered 1-10).

Comment: What should I use that will go numerically instead of alphabetically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command shows you how you sort the base name (file name without extension) of your input files first *lexically*, by the text before the `_`, and then *numerically*, by the number following the `_`:

```
# The input simulates dir (Get-ChildItem) output.
@{ BaseName = 'log_10' }, @{ BaseName ='log_9' }, @{ BaseName = 'log_2' } | 
  Sort-Object { ($_.BaseName -split '_')[0] }, { [int] ($_.BaseName -split '_')[-1] }
```

The above yields the following - note the correct numerical sorting:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
BaseName                       log_2
BaseName                       log_9
BaseName                       log_10
```